# how to pass one-to-many from controller to view in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, one-to-many, icollection

Ok so this would be after changes that you guys helped me with , im assuming im getting a syntax error somewhere

View

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>County's for </h2> 

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create",new { id = Model.ClientID },null) 
</p>


<table>
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County) 
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Note) 
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment) 
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Countys) {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CountyID }) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CountyID }) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CountyID })
    </td>

</tr>
}

</table>
```

Model Clients

```
 [Table("Clients")]
public class Clients
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string LogoLocation { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public int Authorized { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Countys> Countys { get; set; }

}
```

Model Countys

```
 [Table("Countys")]
public class Countys
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int CountyID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TownShips> Townships { get; set; }

}
```

Countys controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
var cnty = from r in db.Clients
where r.ClientID == id
select r;
if (cnty != null)
{
return View(cnty); // View returns an error here
}
return HttpNotFound();
```

View is returning an error but i cannot step into it ... to find out what it is ... ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, the data needed by the view is on a different level than what's being passed.  You're currently sending an `IEnumerable<Countys>` to the view.  But, as you ask, what happens when the enumeration is empty?  Where can the view get the other pieces of data that it needs?  (In this case the `ClientID`.)

What the view *actually* needs is a `Clients`.  Because it's looking for a piece of `Clients`-level data, namely the `ClientID`.  Sure, that data also exists on `Countys` objects, but that's immaterial to the conceptual nature of the data itself.  The view in this case is showing information about a `Clients` object.  Specifically:

```
int ClientID
IEnumerable<Countys> Countys
```

If the latter of those two isn't empty then the former *can* be discerned directly from that data.  It might also be discerned from entirely different and unrelated data as well.  But the point is that the view is conceptually acting on a `Clients` level, not on an `IEnumerable<Countys>` level.

So you'd change the view accordingly, and pass it the object that it needs:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var client = (from r in db.Clients
                 where r.ClientID == id
                 select r).SingleOrDefault();

    if (client != null)
        return View(client);

    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: Ok great, how would one access that County in the view then if you don't mind me asking because I did try this aswell, currently at the very top of my view  - - @model IEnumerable<OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients> - - and i used to displayNamefor(model => model.County) but thats if i used modeldata.countys how would i access the passed Countys?

Comment: @Pakk: Why is your model an `IEnumerable<Clients>`?  Don't you only need a single `Clients` object?  As for the passed `Countys` values... There is no field called `County` on the `Clients` object.  The field on your `Clients` object is called `Countys`, and it contains an enumeration of an entire object, so I'm not sure how the framework would interpret a "display name" for that property.  In the view, isn't there a loop through that property into the enumeration?  The enumerated object in that loop would be of type `Countys` so that should have a `County` property.

Comment: Yeah i believe you are right , 1 client many county that has many townships that has many ..... aso. 

So I'm passing Clients but in my view i don't want to make it an Ienumerable<>? - im new at this and i can see why im not looping through my clients since im passing the ID that i do want, so how would one reference jsut the one client ( or do i just take off the Ienumerable keyword) ?

Comment: @Pakk: Since the view is for a single `Clients` object then its model declaration would be `@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients`  (Perhaps the naming of the types is causing the confusion?  A single instance of a "client" is called `Clients`, which is very unintuitive.  It gets even more unintuitive when you have a list of `Countys` objects called `Countys`.)

Comment: ok so that makes sence then i suppose , i called them clients because im going to use the same model for a list of clients at some point for an admin page... but back to the issue at hand a simple Client.(Name of field in countys) should get me the right data?

Comment: @Pakk: There should be a loop in that HTML table, shouldn't there?  It would be displaying one row for each `Countys` instance associated with that `Clients` instance.  For the action link, you can add route values to it as an anonymous object.  Something like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "ControllerName", new { id = model.ClientID }, null)` which uses one of several available overloads for that function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx

Comment: right , but you had me change the @ model from Ienumerable<Countys> to 
@Model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients therefor can't loop ... or did i understand you wrong?

Comment: @Pakk: You can loop through the `Countys` *property* that's on the model.  Something like: `foreach (var county in model.Countys)`

Comment: -.- will try that that can only make sence

Comment: Updated the question to show what I have in my code now, I have no syntax error via the error msg so im confused on why its bringing up an error and 2ndly why i can't step through to fix the issue... any ideas ?

Comment: @Pakk: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)` won't work in this case.  But you're in luck, because there's a simple solution.  `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Countys.First().County)` *should* work.  It's counter-intuitive because `.First()` should throw an exception if the enumeration is empty, but in this case the runtime isn't actually executing that statement but instead following the type and using reflection to determine the field it needs.

Comment: if i were to comment out everything exept a title , and @ model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients, I still get an error... in the same condition and removing the line @ model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients i get a view displayed..... ideas on why that erroring?

Comment: @Pakk: What is the error?  It might be something entirely unrelated to the question at hand and deserving of a completely new question.  The original issue was how to pass a different type of model to the view, which we've done.

Comment: Yeah kinda.... I can't get to the error and I've done exactly what you had advised to me , im just assuming the changed made this error appear... I cannot step through any further then the controller level, and i know that taking out "@ model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients" will solve the error, therefor asked if you had another way or knew why it was erroring .... possible hint, the ienumerable didnt error?

Comment: @Pakk: Unless I know what the error is then there isn't much I can do to advise on it, sorry.

Comment: yeah ok maybe ill just make another question, Im used to vb.net winforms stepping through literarly everything,... here when i get to my view it jsut jumps to the error page giving me not even the slightest clue about what the error could possibly be

Comment: im going to go ahead and open up another question aparantly finding out how to debug mvc4 razor views because i can't get to it and if it runs fine will then mark as correct, thanks for your help david

Answer (score 2):

You should be, for extensibility reasons, creating ViewModels that are not part of your domain model and passing those into just about all your view.

View Model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
  public int ClientID { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

View(.cshtml):

```
@model OilNGasWeb.Models.Home.IndexViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>County's for </h2> 

<p>
  // send a ClientID with this action link
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { clientid = Model.ClientID } ) 
</p>

//... etc
```

I'd also recommend to actually spell out your variables.  It all gets compiled down, so it's typically better to write maintainable code over short handing variables.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  //Lambda (just for an example, there is nothing wrong with LINQ expressions)
  var client = db.Clients
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientID == id);

  if (client != null)
  {
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.ClientID = id;
    model.Clients = // some value I don't understand

    // My preference/opinion (programming religion) is to prefix with this
    // so others know if the method is *this* class, *base* class etc
    return this.View(model); 
  }

  return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain "public Guid ClientID { get; set; }" im confused on how it knows to reference the ClientID table and its ID ...

Comment: Updated per your comments.

Comment: just btw , oddly enough nothing worked linq or lambda, but this did **[Bind(Prefix="id")] int CID)
        {
            var clnt = db.Clients.Find(CID);

            if (clnt != null)
            { 
                return View(clnt);
            }

            return HttpNotFound();**

Comment: I ment to say nothing was passed exept ClientID, from the Client Model using Linq or Lambda , had to find this BIND method and it passed all my models data, was wierd wanted to  update everyone