# How can I debug mvc4 razor views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor

I'm used to C# and vb.net winforms, and usually can find all the errors I need just by setting a breakpoint and stepping through my code.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm placing a breakpoint here:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var cnty = from r in db.Clients
               where r.ClientID == id
               select r;

    if (cnty != null) // breakpoint here
    {
        return View(cnty); // F11 jumps over this section of code returning me to the error page below.
    }
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Yet again I have no clue where or why it errored out exactly. How can I find out why or better yet what error it is throwing?

I'm using VS2012 mvc4 c#.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but `cnty` will never be `null`.  It may be _empty_, but not `null`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put breakpoints in your view itself.  You can place breakpoints on anything using razor syntax such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink
@{ var x = model.x; }
```

If you are getting a null reference exception, put breakpoints on places where you consume the model in your view.

Comment: suppose that is an issue, since im setting a breakpoint at the very first, and even all lines in my view... non of them stop the program from executing, ideas?

Comment: What browser are you debugging in?  If IE, you may run into some issues.  In IE, click Tools->internet options->advanced tab -> uncheck Disable script debugging.

Comment: Couple things then.  Clean your solution.  Rebuilt your solution.  Make sure your web project is set to the startup project.  That SHOULD get your breakpoints hit.  Also, what is the error that you're getting?  Use the try/catch trick to snag it.  That would help

Comment: Sorry work got distrccting for a couple of days, David.. when i put in the try catch it won't even go that far , as soon as i get to the call of the view it breaks away , can't step into the razor view code...

Comment: Are you by chance doing any @Html.RenderPartial calls in your razor view?  I'm wondering if by chance something is not renderable in the view itself

Comment: Sorry no i have literarly everything commented out exept @model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients

Comment: Unfortunately, without some error there's no way to help you :(

Comment: Do i have to do something special to see errors in Firefox? or redirect it to show me stacktrance instead of the pretty error of "something went wrong"?

Comment: If you're having rendering of the view errors, you should be able to try/catch them and throw the error, in visual studio if you're attached to the debugger

Answer (score 4):

It would help to see the exception you are seeing. I'm guessing that you are seeing an exception when the page renders. As "David L" identified above, you want to set your breakpoint in the Razor view (`Index.cshtml`).

**But why?**

It helps to understand the lifecycle of a request/response in MVC. Here is the [first example I found with a visual](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/TbR0041112-Asp.net-MVC-Request-Life-Cycle.html). There are sure to be others.

- Request is routed to your Controller
- The Controller returns a `ActionResult`: `return View(cnty);`
- MVC passes the `ActionResult` to your View
- The exception occurs in your `Index.cshtml` when attempting to use the `ActionResult`.

I'm going to speculate that it has something to do with a disposed DB context object. Depending on the ORM you are using, the result of

```
from r in db.Clients
where r.ClientID == id
select r
```

is an `IQueryable<Client>`. You may be surprised to find out that your code has not yet contacted the database before `return View(cnty);` is executed. Try this instead:

```
return View(cnty.ToList());
```

Again, the exact error you are seeing is important. My suggestion presumes `Index.cshtml` begins with:

```
@model IEnumerable<Client>
```

**Update:**

Per OP's comment below, the stack trace is not available. There are many questions dedicated to seeing the stack trace in your browser during development. At least confirm that the following is set in your `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode ="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Yeah thats was my hole point about my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279306/how-to-pass-one-to-many-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc4/17279523?noredirect=1#comment25053983_17279523 -- here I was told to not use Ienumerable<client> because of the hierachy data im trying to use and for the expetion you are asking me for, Im not getting anything, no error , no exeption , just the page with error on it , in other words I don't konw how to find the expetion

Comment: Is the web server on the same machine as your browser?

Comment: Then you should see the stack trace in your browser. We need the stack trace to help you. Does your `web.config` have `<customErrors mode="Off" />`?

Comment: no its on, maybe this stacktrace is the issue how would i start that, or would it auto throw and show me?

Comment: @Ed - None of my breakpoints in my View were being hit, but I was getting no stack trace, just HTTP 500 error. That is until I set <customErrors mode ="Off" />. Then I got the stack trace which told me my model being passed was wrong. I fixed that then was able to step through the view. +1 for <customErrors mode ="Off" />.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a `try` block.  Your exception will be available in the catch block for inspection, reporting, etc.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            try
            {
            var cnty = from r in db.Clients
                       where r.ClientID == id
                       select r;

            if (cnty != null) // breakpoint here
            {
                return View(cnty); // F11 jumps over this section of code returning me to the error page below.
            }
            return HttpNotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                  //report error
            }
        }
```

Comment: While an excellent tip, this doesn't actually help him debug the View itself