# passing variables / models in mvc 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller, view

Ok so i have 2 models

> Model Clients

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Clients
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string LogoLocation { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public int Authorized { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Countys> Countys { get; set; }

}
```

> Model Countys

```
[Table("Countys")]
public class Countys
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int CountyID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TownShips> Townships { get; set; }

}
```

** My Countys Index Controller at this time **

```
     public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var cnty = from r in db.Clients
                   where r.ClientID == id
                   select r;

        if (cnty != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return View(cnty);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        return HttpNotFound();

     }
```

> My view is a standard generated view :

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index"; 
}

<h2>County's for </h2> 

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create",new { id = Model.ClientID },null)
</p>


<table>
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Countys.First().County) 
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Countys.First().Note) 
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Countys.First().Comment) 
    </th>

</tr>
</Table>
```

EXCEPTION :

System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type     'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients]', but this dictionary     requires a model item of type 'OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients'. at     System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) at     System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) at     System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) at     System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) at     System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) at     System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext,     ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.    <InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() at     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter,     ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.    <>c_*DisplayClass1a.<>c*_DisplayClass1c.b_*19() at     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext         controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at     System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass25.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.    b*_20() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass25.        b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult);

Comment: This sounds a *lot* like a previous question, which has some answers already: [how to pass one-to-many from controller to view in mvc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279306/how-to-pass-one-to-many-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc4)

Comment: Yes it does but non of them are a solution for me, I also flagged them to be removed because of duplications was told that reviving them and changing all the code in the questions would not be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view needs a `Clients` object (which includes an enumeration of `Countys` objects), then you need to pass a `Clients` object to your view:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var client = (from r in Clients
                 where r.ClientID == id
                 select r).SingleOrDefault();

    if (client != null)
    {
        return View(client);
    }
    return HttpNotFound();

 }
```

And in the view you'd declare a `Clients` model:

```
@model OilNGasWeb.ModelData.Clients
```

Then in the view you would have access to the information about the `Clients` object as well as the (potentially empty) list of `Countys` objects it contains.  Essentially what's "wrong" with your code is that the view is logically in the context of a `Clients` (it's *really* hard not to just say "Client", you might want to work on the class names), but all you're giving it is an enumeration of `Countys` objects.

Note: For safer code, you'll probably want to initialize that enumeration to whatever its value should be, in case it isn't populated in the event that it's an empty list.  You'd do this in the class' constructor.  For example, if you want to initialize it to a `List<Countys>` then the constructor might be something like this:

```
public Clients()
{
    Countys = new List<Countys>();
}
```

That way the property is never `null`, at worst it's an empty list which is a lot easier to manage in the view.

Comment: awesome could you please give me sample syntax of how to get to the the data ... I am used to vb.net and have been trying to use             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.Countys.CountyName ( or w/e field )

Comment: @Pakk: Try something like: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.Countys.First().CountyName)`  It's a bit unintuitive since one would *expect* `.First()` to throw an exception on an empty list.  But in this case the HTML helper method isn't actually executing that line.  It's just following the referenced type via reflection.  So even on an empty list `.First()` should work in this case.  (Though based on your code I'm not sure what type `item` is in this example.  I would expect something like `Model.Countys.First().CountyName` but I can't be certain.)

Comment: ok I changed my code around could you advise on why its not working? Or would this be a different question

Comment: @Pakk: Why is your model an `IEnumerable` of `Clients`?  (Note: I had a typo in my answer, the model should be a `Clients` object and not a `Countys` object.  I've corrected it now.)  You're only using one `Clients` object, right?

Comment: yes i am only using Clients object now ( removed the Ienumerable ) also im getting into the view if it is an Ienumerable if it is not its erroring out, having issues seeing the error try / catch and or stepping into it doesnt seem to work. give me a few

Comment: also, i implemented the try catch in the index action of Countys Controller  instead of the view itself , am i doing it wrong because it skipps my catch, acts like it ran fine , but displays an error view not a message however anyway

Comment: try
                {
                    return View(cnty);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                }

Comment: alright well thanks for your help, ill come back with an exeption when i find it out

Comment: @Pakk: Any try/catch should definitely be in the controller (or the model) and not in the view.  The view shouldn't really do much more than just build the markup from the data in the model.  What's the error that gets displayed?

Comment: i don't get any error thats the whole point, all i know is that my error page gets displayed. and my try catch hits but never gets to a catch. Also today i found out it is looking for source files while debugging the website... is that normal?

Comment: @Pakk: Does your error page give any indication of what went wrong?  Usually on an ASP.NET MVC error page the model is `@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo`, and the error can be found in `@Model.Exception`.  Your try/catch isn't catching anything because the only thing in the try block is a `return` statement.  The function is successfully returning a value, the error happens somewhere else when something tries to use that value.

Comment: now we can get somewhere .... i knew you could get an error somehow, thanks david... ill post the exception above

Comment: @Pakk: There's a mismatch between the type the view is expecting and the type you're passing into it.  Based on the most recent LINQ query in your question it looks like you're passing in an enumeration of `Clients` objects (even though there may only be one in that enumeration).  You need to pass in a single instance of a `Clients` object, as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: sorry about that i updated my code above to give you a more up-to-date look at the code

Comment: also david, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281721/how-can-i-debug-mvc4-razor-views its the question i started because i couldnt find out how to get expetions, if you would put your ' @ Pakk: Does your error page give any indication of what went wrong? Usually on an ASP.NET MVC error page the model is @ model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo, and the error can be found in @ Model.Exception. Your try/catch isn't catching anything because the only thing in the try block is a return statement. The function is successfully returning a value, the error' .. there i can vote on it.

Comment: @Pakk: You've updated the code with your try/catch, but completely missed the `.SingleOrDefault()`.  Look, I don't want to sound rude, but you're requiring a *lot* of hand-holding here.  Stack Overflow is happy to help answer questions, but I can't debug every line of your code for you.  Please, walk through some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and learn not just the framework but programming logic in general.  Try to understand the difference between two different object types, between an instance and a collection of instances, how to invoke functions and properties on those instances, and so on.

Comment: I completely understand thanks for you help, is there any books / videos you would recomend. I understand the types but MVC jsut throwing me around giving me a run for it. Then commands are completely seperate issue. Thanks for your help.